# Basic Php/Mysql Search: rowCount() returning error

Tags: php

I am developing a very basic php/mysql search. The search is based on a filter criteria of the value chosen in the dropdown menu. There are three options `Whole Site`, `Pages`, `Blogs`. In my php code I prepare the sql statements and then execute accordingly to the chosen filter. I am getting an error on `$count = $query->rowCount()` but most interesting when I try to echo the results from the query I am getting `1`. How can I display the correct values and overcome the error? [DEMO](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/search.php)

*PHP/Mysql*

```
<?php
require("db_con/db_con.php");
$search_output = "";
if(isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != ""){
  $searchquery = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['searchquery']);
  if($_POST['filter1'] == "Whole Site"){
    $sqlCommand = $db_con->prepare("(SELECT id, page_title AS title FROM pages WHERE MATCH (page_title,page_body) AGAINST ('$searchquery')) UNION (SELECT id, blog_title AS title FROM blog WHERE MATCH (blog_title,blog_body) AGAINST ('$searchquery'))");
  } else if($_POST['filter1'] == "Pages"){
    $sqlCommand = $db_con->prepare("SELECT id, page_title AS title FROM pages WHERE MATCH (page_title,page_body) AGAINST ('$searchquery')");
  } else if($_POST['filter1'] == "Blog"){
    $sqlCommand = $db_con->prepare("SELECT id, blog_title AS title FROM blog WHERE MATCH (blog_title,blog_body) AGAINST ('$searchquery')");
  }

    $query = $sqlCommand->execute();
    $count = $query->rowCount();
  if($count > 1){
    $search_output .= "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand<hr />";
    $query->fetchAll();
       foreach($row as $query){
         $id = $row["id"];
         $title = $row["title"];
         $search_output .= "Item ID: $id - $title<br />";
        } // close while
  } else {
    $search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand";
  }
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<h2>Search the Exercise Tables</h2>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Search For:
  <input name="searchquery" type="text" size="44" maxlength="88">
Within:
<select name="filter1">
<option value="Whole Site">Whole Site</option>
<option value="Pages">Pages</option>
<option value="Blog">Blog</option>
</select>
<input name="myBtn" type="submit">
<br />
</form>
<div>
<?php echo $search_output; ?>
```

Comment: `rowCount()` is a method of `$sqlCommand` the statement, not its return value.  `$sqlCommand->rowCount()`

Comment: You get `1` because the return of `PDOStatement::execute()` is `true/false` on success/failure. Your query succeeded, so the variable `$query` holds the value `true.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Fixed the incompatibility issue. It was originally in `mysql_` but now I am using this with `PDO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rowCount() function only returns the number of rows affected by DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statements.  To get a count of rows for a SELECT statement you have to do a separate query like this:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fruit WHERE calories > 100";
if ($res = $conn->query($sql)) {

  /* Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement */
  if ($res->fetchColumn() > 0) {

         /* Issue the real SELECT statement and work with the results */
         $sql = "SELECT name FROM fruit WHERE calories > 100";
         foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
           print "Name: " .  $row['NAME'] . "\n";
         }
    } else { /* No rows matched -- do something else */
      print "No rows matched the query.";
    }
}

$res = null;
$conn = null;
?>
```

This is from the PHP manual, here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Answer (score -1):

Try `$fetchColumn` instead of `$rowCount`

Comment: The OP is not using a variable called `$rowCount`. Maybe you are referring to using a separate "count" query, as mentioned by @BoydDensmore?